# What does a principal represent

Tags: .net, authentication

In .net authentication, one of the core concepts is called a principal, and there are a bunch of types representing a principal, like `IPrincipal` and its implementors.

What (real-world or not) concept does a principal represent?

Comment: If you [read the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.principal.iprincipal?view=net-5.0) you can also see the derived types that implement the interface.

Comment: Yes, I know that, but unfortunately that doesn't help me understand what real-world concept a principal represents.